# Pi Product Simplification Rules

Tags: infinite-product

I wanted to know the "rules" for Infinite Products. For example, if you have a factorial, what do you do? A power? A power with two variables?

What are some quick things I can look at and immediately know the simplification of, basically?

Edit: here is an example:

$\lambda * e^{-\lambda * y_i}$

I have to find this infinite product from i=1 to inf.. how? I dont want to know how to do *just* this problem. I want to be able to do it for all.

Comment: This is a little vague. Can you please be a little bit more specific about what you want?

Comment: Sure. I am studying statistics, and we just reached max likelihood estimates. If you don't know what that is, that's fine; one of the steps (the first one, actually) is to find the Likelihood of a given function. I am given many different kinds of funky functions with exponents, factorials, and multiple variables. Look at one of the examples that is (now) provided in the question. How in the world do I even begin to tackle that? What are the fundamental rules of... simplification?

Comment: "(now) provided in the question" I don't see any examples.

Comment: Yes... sorry. I forgot to save edit.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find the answer to this anywhere on the internet, or on math stack exchange or cross validated (which are the only two communities I belong to).  I ended up having to ask a friend, who provided the following explanation based on our notes and problem sets from the statistics course we are both taking.  For that reason, I unfortunately can't provide any specific references, but these are the rules that she explained to me, which have been reverse engineered from the examples that we have seen in the class:

Consider the terms of the likelihood function to be in three, mutually exclusive categories.

(1) Terms which do not include the indexed term anywhere: Examples includes $\lambda$ (from your example), or $\frac{1}{2}$. Consider these as constants and raise each to the *nth* power.

(2) Terms which include the indexed term in the exponent (but the indexed term is not a factorial). Examples includes ${e}^{x_i}$, ${e}^{3*(x_i-\mu)}$: Convert the exponent to the sum over the range of the indexed term, i.e. for the first example, ${e}^{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}$.

(3) Terms which include the indexed term as the base value, or where it is a factorial anywhere: No simplification is possible.

Since we are usually using this as a first step to take the derivative with respect to the parameter, the factorials or base values of the indexed values will usually drop out in the derivation and so not really matter that we can't simplify these any further.

I am sharing in part to confirm our understanding; if any of the above is incorrect, please advise.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to this question (the question is quite a bit more broad than your answer). Also, there are plenty of examples of everything you've mentioned here on this site.

Comment: Hi @DonThousand, could you provide a link to the examples you're referring to?

Comment: There are too many to link here. A quick search on infinite products gets you all you need. For example, your bullet #2 is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447430/relating-infinite-product-and-infinite-sums?rq=1).

Comment: Hm, I had based my answer off of his clarifying point, which had to do with estimating maximum likelihoods for statistics. None of the posts which you refer to or that I was able to find had an application for that since the referenced rules are scattered about and embedded in long specific proofs, for the most part, and therefore difficult to ascertain generalized versus specific results. I found it odd that this was on maths rather cross validated, but oh, well. Anyways, that is just to provide some context, but I am sorry if this is a duplicate or does not adequately address the question.

Comment: Hopefully someone else can answer more comprehensively.